# angular router navigate not working after successful login

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have below code for login and i am using canActivate guard for my routes:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  returnUrl: string;

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo,private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private authService:AuthService) {
    if (this.authService.currentUserValue) {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/home/dashboard';
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
    }
  }
}
```

And below are the routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: 'customer', component: CustomerComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/home/customer', pathMatch: 'full' },
      ]
  }, 
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

but after successful login router not redirecting to the given returnUrl

Comment: Can you provide an example of how your `returnUrl` would look?

Comment: Try this.router.navigate("/dashboard") first and then if it work you know what is the problem.

Comment: @nash11 "/home/dashboard" this is my returnUrl

Comment: That's the default for your `returnUrl`. Could you just add an example of how your URL looks in the browser when you have a `returnUrl` in the query params.